# ReactJS problem with changing direction of translateX() transformation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-transitions

Given :

```js
function App() {        
        const [xPos, setXPos ] = React.useState(0);
    const [style, setStyle] = React.useState({transform: `translateX(${xPos}px)`});
  
    const onClick =(direction) => {
       (direction === "left") ? setXPos(x => x-100) : setXPos(x => x +100);
       setStyle({transform: `translateX(${xPos}px)`});
           console.log(xPos)
        }

    return (
          <div className="main_container">
             <button className="left_button" onClick={() => onClick("left")}>slide left</button>
             <div className="forecast_slider" >
                <div className="forecast_container" style={style} > 
                   {forecastBuilder()}
                </div>
             </div>
             <button className="right_button" onClick={() => onClick("right")}>slide right</button>
          </div>
       )
   }

const forecastBuilder = () => {
const cell = [];
  for(var i = 1 ; i < 8 ; i++){
    cell.push(
        <div className={i}>
        {i}
        <img src="https://imgs.michaels.com/MAM/assets/1/5E3C12034D34434F8A9BAAFDDF0F8E1B/img/0E9397ED92304202B4A25D7387A74515/M10118706_2.jpg" width="100" height="80" border="1px solid black" />
        <br></br>
        <span>day {i}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return cell;
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.main_container {
  display:flex;
}
.forecast_container { 
    display: flex;
    width: 510px;
    height: 130px;
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    
    transition: transform 250ms;
  }
  .forecast_slider {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  
     overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="app"></div>
```

with [JSFiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/061g5s3x/) ,

I want to make the `translateX()` animation increment and decrement normally. Currently, I have to click twice a button to *change the direction*. I have no clue why this is happening. I tried setting the initial `style`'s transform parameter to `0px`. I haven't tried other things since honestly, I am short of ideas, this bug is beyond my understanding of React.

Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you try to use the updated `xPos` state in your `onClick` handler right after you "updated" it: `` setStyle({transform: `translateX(${xPos}px)`}) ``

Don't forget that `useState` is asynchronous just like `setState` in class components. You can't update the state on one line and assume it's already changed on the next one. You'll likely use the unchanged state.

Create a new variable and update both states using that one:

```js
function App() {
  const [xPos, setXPos] = React.useState(0);
  const [style, setStyle] = React.useState({
    transform: `translateX(${xPos}px)`,
  });

  const onClick = (direction) => {
    let x = direction === 'left' ? xPos - 100 : xPos + 100
    setXPos(x)
    setStyle({ transform: `translateX(${x}px)` });
    console.log(xPos);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main_container">
      <button className="left_button" onClick={() => onClick('left')}>
        slide left
      </button>
      <div className="forecast_slider">
        <div className="forecast_container" style={style}>
          {forecastBuilder()}
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="right_button" onClick={() => onClick('right')}>
        slide right
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const forecastBuilder = () => {
  const cell = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    cell.push(
      <div className={i}>
        {i}
        <img
          src="https://imgs.michaels.com/MAM/assets/1/5E3C12034D34434F8A9BAAFDDF0F8E1B/img/0E9397ED92304202B4A25D7387A74515/M10118706_2.jpg"
          width="100"
          height="80"
          border="1px solid black"
        />
        <br></br>
        <span>day {i}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return cell;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
.main_container {
  display: flex;
}

.forecast_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 510px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}

.forecast_slider {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Also, you could simply get rid of the `useStyles` hook as it's just some extra fluff around `xPos`:

```js
function App() {
  const [xPos, setXPos] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="main_container">
      <button className="left_button" onClick={() => setXPos(xPos - 100)}>
        slide left
      </button>
      <div className="forecast_slider">
        <div className="forecast_container" style={{ transform: `translateX(${xPos}px)` }}>
          {forecastBuilder()}
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="right_button" onClick={() => setXPos(xPos + 100)}>
        slide right
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const forecastBuilder = () => {
  const cell = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    cell.push(
      <div className={i}>
        {i}
        <img
          src="https://imgs.michaels.com/MAM/assets/1/5E3C12034D34434F8A9BAAFDDF0F8E1B/img/0E9397ED92304202B4A25D7387A74515/M10118706_2.jpg"
          width="100"
          height="80"
          border="1px solid black"
        />
        <br></br>
        <span>day {i}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return cell;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
.main_container {
  display: flex;
}

.forecast_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 510px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 250ms;
}

.forecast_slider {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer was found.

Setting a state is not synchronous and there is no reason to store `style` in an additional state hook since it's just one parameter and can be passed in the render function imemdiately.

```
    const [xPos, setXPos ] = React.useState(0);
  
    const onClick =(direction) => {
       (direction === "left") ? setXPos(x => x-100) : setXPos(x => x +100);
    }

    return (
     <div className="main_container">
     <button className="left_button" onClick={() => onClick("left")}>slide left</button>
     <div className="forecast_slider" >
       <div className="forecast_container" style={{transform : `translateX(${xPos}px)`}} > 
        {forecastBuilder()}
       </div>
     </div>
      <button className="right_button" onClick={() => onClick("right")}>slide right</button>
     </div>
  )
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: And my answer is one minute late, can't believe it :)

Comment: @I gave you the reputation nevertheless, thank you for the help on the detailed answer :) !